# Running jRuby + Rails inside of Tomcat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, tomcat, jruby

I am currently using a platform where multiple web applications must interact with each other in a frameset. This set of web applications and the frameset is hosted on Tomcat.

Now the application we're working on is developed with jRuby and Rails. Is there anyway I can run my development environment inside of Tomcat similar to just running the `jRuby -S Rails Server` command so I can effectively debug?

The only way I've found is to generate a war using warble and *then* modifying the exploded war which seems really hacky. Any thoughts?

EDIT: I think my best bet is to generate a war, gut it, use symbolic links and figure out what gems / libs I need to copy from the war generation process. It's the best way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

one option to explore: deploy a little servlet to Tomcat which returns

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is a ton of JavaScript shared between the different web applications (the main reason why they're on the same server) so a redirect won't work.

Answer (score 0):

So far the best solution I have found is to setup a reverse proxy with Tomcat and point it to the Rails development server. This allows it to run, as expected on the client side, while still giving me debug control.

When I get a chance to do some more testing I'll edit my answer to include additional information.

Answer (score 0):

go to the `webapps` folder in tomcat where you have deployed the war file, then find the `web.xml` file inside the expanded war file

The path to this file is generally `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/your-project-here/WEB-INF/web.xml` and inside this file you should find the

Changing this is one way to go about.

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>rails.env</param-name>
    <param-value>production</param-value>
  </context-param>
```